One-Loop beta function for gauge couplings
I am currently doing my homework on Standard Model one-loop correction. When I am reading Quantum Field Theory by Mark Srednicki and Journeys Beyond the Standard Model by Pierre Ramond, I notice some discrepancies between the two book. Perhaps some of my doubts have been answered in this
question, but more puzzles come in and I decided to set up a new question. In Srednicki’s book, the beta function of non-Abelian gauge is:
$$
\beta (g)=-[\frac{11}{3}T(A) -\frac{4}{3} n_{F}T(R)] \frac{g^3}{16 {\pi}^2}+\mathcal{O}({g^5}). \tag{71.34}
$$
After substituting the group algebra for $SU(3)$, which includes $T(A)=3$ and $T(R)=\frac{1}{2}$, also the fermions in the $SU(3)$ fundamental representation is $n_F =6$, then we can obtain:
$$
\beta (g)=-(11- \frac{2}{3} n_{F}) \frac{g^3}{16 {\pi}^2}.
$$
The result is consistent with the same book on page 631
$$
\mu \frac{d}{d \mu }g_i=\frac{b_i}{16{\pi }^2 }{g_i}^3 \tag{97.26}
$$
$$
 b_1=\frac{4}{3}n-11 \tag{97.27}
$$ where $n=3$ refers to the number of generations.
\ 
However there seems to be some problems in $SU(2)$ case, as  there is no Dirac Fermions in $SU(2)$, this group only couples to left-handed Weyl Field. Then how can we start from (71.34) to arrive at:
$$
 b_2=-\frac{22}{3}+\frac{4}{3}n+\frac{1}{6}. \tag{97.28}
$$
My next puzzle is the $U(1)$ coupling, Srednicki gives the result:
$$
 b_1=+\frac{20}{9}n+\frac{1}{6}. \tag{97.29}
$$
This result seem to be capable of yielding the same result with vector QED. However, Pierre Ramond gives a different result on page 172 of his book:
$$
b=\frac{11}{3}C_{adj}-\frac{2}{3}\Sigma_f C_f-\frac{1}{6} \Sigma_h C_h \tag{6.38}
$$
$$
 b_1=\frac{4}{3}n_{fam}-\frac{1}{10}. \tag{6.39}
$$
The sign difference is just from convention and both books give the same $b_2$ and $b_3$. But for $b_1$ the factors attached to the family number are manifestly different!
\ 
So what is exactly going on here?

Comment to the post (v2): Eq. (71.34) is labelled (73.41) in by Srednicki copy.
